# Tab autocompletion not working in Datacamp

Tags: r

I am following courses on R with Datacamp. It works with an online R environment where code can be entered directly in the browser.

But my tab-autocompletion is not working correctly. Often it repeats the first characters of the variable or function that I want to auto-complete. Very annoying.

To give you a specific example: the variable "education" would become "ededucation" and I would have to manually remove the first two characters. It would save me a lot of time if it would work correctly.

On my computer, outside Datacamp, I work with RStudio and there it just works as it should. How can I make it work in the online environment of datacamp too?

Answer (score 0):

I did observe the same behaviour within the DataCamp environment. I tried using Firefox as well as Safari and IE - still no change! We should report this issue to the DataCamp staff, maybe they will fix it!

Comment: I was already wondering if it was my setup. But seeing that you have the problem too, makes me think it is something else.

Comment: I have notified Datacamp support. They have just updated the system and it looks somewhat different. It seems better, but not completely gone. How is your experience?

Comment: It seems it has something to do with the connection. Because it happens especially when I am on my mobile hotspot